# Accordion panel on click scrolls to the bottom of page then back up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have an accordion on mobile using the bootstap tab collapse.js. Everything works as should, but when the user clicks on to the next panel below, it seems to scroll them down the page and then back up to the container they clicked.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#pdp-tabs-accordion .js-tabcollapse-panel-heading', function () {
    self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('scrolling to');
        console.log(self.closest('.panel'));
        ScrollToElement(self.closest('.panel'), 95);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a aria-controls="advice" role="tab" data-toggle="collapse" class="js-tabcollapse-panel-heading collapsed" data-parent="#pdp-tabs-accordion" aria-expanded="false">Centre</a></h4>   </div>  

<div id="advicecentre-collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">       <div class="panel-body js-tabcollapse-panel-body">       
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-xl-6 col-xl-offset-3">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="product-misc product-misc--advice-centre" id="advice-centre">


                              <h3>Centre</h3>
                              <p>We have selected the following pages from our Advice Centre as possibly the most relevant for you.</p>
                              <div class="row">
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/what-is-dwr-durable-water-repellent-coating-snowboardski-jackets" title="What is DWR? = Durable Water Repellent Coating - Snowboard/Ski Jackets">What is DWR?</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/dwr-coated-fabrics-washing-care-instructions-advice-" title="DWR Coated Fabrics - Washing &amp; Care Instructions &amp; Advice ">DWR Washing &amp; Care</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/waterproof-ratings-snowboard-ski-jackets-what-the-numbers-mean" title="Waterproof Ratings – Snowboard &amp; Ski Jackets - What the Numbers Mean">Waterproof Ratings Explained</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/critically-taped-v-fully-taped-waterproof-seams-snowboardski-jackets" title="Critically Taped v Fully Taped Waterproof Seams - Snowboard/Ski Jackets">Waterproof Seams Explained</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/which-is-best-2-25-or-3-layer-breathable-waterproof-fabric-goretex" title="Which is Best? 2. 2.5 or 3 Layer Breathable Waterproof Fabric / Gore-Tex">2, 2.5 or 3 Layer Fabric?</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/buying-guides/keeping-warm-in-the-snow-the-absolute-guide-to-layering" title="Keeping Warm In The Snow - The Absolute Guide to Layering">Keeping Warm In The Snow</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                  <p>We have hundreds more pages, including more <a href="/buying-guides" target="_blank">Buying Guides</a> and <a href="/size-charts" target="_blank">Size Chart</a>.</p>
                              </div>
                                                              <h3 class="margin-top">Size Charts</h3>
                              <div class="row" id="size-charts">
                                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                                          <div class="product-misc__item" itemprop="productID">
                                              <a href="/size-charts/686-mens-snowboard-jackets-size-chart" title="686 - Men's Snowboard Jackets Size Chart">686 - Men's Snowboard Jackets Size Chart</a>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                              </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>   
  </div>
  </div>
```

Any suggestions or ideas you might have to why this is happening would be great.

thanks in adavance!

Comment: is there an `a` tag with `href="#"` included in the panel? Or better, include your html in the question as well.

Comment: @empiric There is a ```href="#PanelID"```

Comment: Does an element with ID `PanelID` exist? If not, there is your problem, the site tries to scroll to an element that does not exist so it most likely just scroll to the bottom and then your second waiting time from `setTimeout` is over and js scroll to the position of the next panel

Comment: Either add `preventDefault()` to your click function or reference the proper anchor in your `href` . I would suggest to the first as you want to scroll with your JS

Comment: @empiric  I'll give them a crack, nice one